# Работа с JS в инспекторе Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome

В Chrome есть стандартный элемент Web Inspector. А в нем Console на JS.
Я работаю с одним приложением на flash, в нем также открывается Web Inspector.

В этом моем приложении выскакивают элементы (текст), они быстро обновляются. С помощью исследования элемента в браузере, я могу видеть код интересующего меня элемента, или производить с ним какие то операции, например редактирование, изменение шрифтов, положения..

Меня интересует как автоматизировать копирование нужного мне элемента, например в текстовый редактор. Вручную это можно делать просто мышкой, правой кнопкой по элементу в дереве и выбрать copy, или можно прописать в консоли функцию copy().

Я не умею работать в JS. Вообще, я пишу код в Python, для которого нужны данные (быстро обновляющийся текст), которые я беру с веб страницы. Смысл такой - копировать эти данные в текстовый редактор, а уж оттуда я их открою и прочитаю в Питоне.

Как написать команду для консоли, которая будет выполнять это самое копирование? На примере этой страницы и выделенного (на скриншоте) элемента "ЗАДАТЬ ВОПРОС".[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше селениум. Можно на питоне. Ну или ещё что, что сможет чужими приложениями управлять. Либо расширение, которое будет делать то же самое без консоли. Но я не уверен, есть ли у расширений доступ к буферу обмена. Кстати, если консоль отсоединить, то можно показать консоль для консоли через ctrl+shift+i.

Comment: Расширения для редактирования внешнего вида, типа style bot могут только, собственно, цвета и шрифты менять. По-моему копировать, да и вообще видеть и распознавать для копирования наполнение элемента не могут.

Comment: Могут. А вот могут ли копировать - не факт.